# Jenkins and ClearCase plugin not copying files to workspace

Tags: jenkins, clearcase

We are using the ClearCase plugin for Jenkins (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin) and we are running into an issue where we use a dynamic view and the plugin detects changes in the source files in the view and kicks off the build but does not copy files from the view to the Jenkins workspace.

No error message. No failed build message. Just nothing.

Is this working as designed? How are other folks getting the files that have changed from the view?

Comment: What version of ClearCase and Jenkins are you using? What OS Jenkins is running on?

Comment: We are using CC 7.0.1.0 and Jenkins 1.461. After some digging, and I could be wrong, it looks like the idea is that dynamic views are designed to be stored remotely. (Back in the bad old days hard drives were expensive and developers couldn't afford to store source code locally.) Digging into the plugin source code in DynamicCheckoutAction.java it looks like it will create a dynamic view on a network share for you but it doesn't copy the code to your Jenkins workspace. To get the file that changed you can look in Jenkins' changelog.xml.

Comment: "will create a dynamic view on a network share": no a dynamic view is always opened on `M:\` or `/view`, but its view *storage* (which exists for a snapshot or a dynamic view) needs to be created on a path accessible by the CC client and the view server (hence the shared path)

Answer (score 1):

Last time I saw a similar case, it was for a dynamic view with:

- incorrect loading rule
- or no loading rules at all (since a dynamic view has no "load rules" at all), which isn't compliant with the [documentation of the plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin):

> Specify one or more load rules - this is required, even with a dynamic view.
>   The load rules are used both for determining the contents of snapshot views and for constructing the "`cleartool lshistory`" command used for polling and generating changelogs.

Note there are [quite a few pending bugs regarding that plugin](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS/component/15503#atl_token=B5BF-G2S8-8N2K-SZ3R%7Cc3e8d9e32834afbd480520d09ee8c6aedd2f47c5%7Clout&selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3acomponent-popularissues-panel), so you might see one of those.
I would make sure the process used by Jenkins can access and copy a file from the dynamic view by making that copy part of a build script, in order if that script (outside of any polling mechanism from the CC plugin) does execute successfully or not.